# google spreadsheet - share to edit but don't overwrite

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I built something like an application/form in a spreadsheet (but not as a form) and would like to share it to friends. They should be able to work with it like with a standalone application or like a form.

Is it somehow possible to share a spreadsheet, so that each user can type in something without effecting the other users?

Comment: Without scripting, you can force a Google Drive file to download or copy with a URL parameter [as outlined here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/). To copy the sheet, it would be: `http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/FILE_ID&newcopy=true`. It should copy the template to the user's Drive. They would  have to share it back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can "protect" both ranges and sheets within a Google Spreadsheet, allowing certain users to edit them while others can only view.

You can this manually or via Google Apps Script using the "protect()" method on the relevant sheets or ranges.

Google Apps Script documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect

Or to do it manually:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en